# Do we need to bind when using raw socket?

Tags: bind, ip-address, raw-sockets, sendto

I am using raw socket to pump specific IP Packets to network. I construct the total IP Packet and send using sendto. 
My question is, what is the need to bind the socket to an IP address, when I am using a raw socket.(Since the source address is filled by the program and not kernel)

Thanks
Libin Jose

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Binding the socket is must. After binding the socket you will get a port, and the port is the actual medium of the transaction of data.